# More efficient to update or rebuild Rails 2.3.X app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-2

I have a Rails 2.3.X app. I plan to hire a developer to either update the site to current Rails standards or rebuild the site. In general, is there a way to evaluate whether it's more cost-effective to update versus rebuild? My preference is to update.

Comment: The most cost effective solution would be not to do anything. What is the business case for needing to update/build?

Comment: I'm inexperienced in Rails, but my understanding is that the 2.3.X app will not benefit from security updates and from updates to gems. Also, because of the differences in coding for Rails 2 versus Rails 4, not updating may mean that contract developers I hire will have trouble programming new features for the web app because they are using Rails 4 coding standards. But, look, if this is totally wrong and if the app can be secure and easily added to in Rails 2, that would make me ecstatic! I'm just basing this off opinion from another couple of developers and trying to get a sense of costs.

Comment: I would focus on the business requirements. What are your users asking for? What do they need? What features will they pay for? Answer these questions first. Once answered assign each feature a priority based on ease of implementation and cost of implementation. Do the features at the top of your list require a rails upgrade? If not then don't spend the money. It's really the users who decide this. HTH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to form a judgement on this, it depends on number of lines, gem dependencies used (more is harder), test coverage (less is harder).

We have tried to upgrade an application of 100.000+ lines from Rails 2 to Rails4. It certainly is a lot of work. Building from scratch is a serious alternative, especially since it is nearly impossible to timebox the upgrade project. We are rebuilding the app. Also, Rails 2.3 is more than 5 years old. I can imagine that your market may have changed and it needs some rework anyway because it is outdated. The last thing I want to mention is tests. If your app has considerable testcoverage, updating may be easier.

Answer (score 1):

I like to present a third option to you.

We had a similar situation. Large Rails 2 application, we ran into security issues and the upgrade of the OS was blocked because of old dependencies.

Instead of updating our app, we switched to Rails LTS. https://railslts.com/

It worked out pretty well.